# How to add CraftCms imperavi redactor custom list of font size options?

Tags: redactor, craftcms

I have a craft 3 website using the imperavi redactor and I'm using the 'fontsize' plugin. I'm trying to limit the amount of font size options the user is able to select.

In the redactor folder I have a json file that is otherwise working. Here is the code I've included that is not working where I try to limit the options to 10, 14, and 18.

```
"plugins": ["customstyles", "alignment", "fontsize"],
"fontsize": ["10", "14", "18"],
```